# How can I override standard modal css in lightning:overlayLib modal instantiation?

Tags: css, modal, lightning-overlaylibrary, overflow

I am running into an issue where part of my component within the modal generated by lightning:overlayLib requires the user to scroll. I want the div that appears to display over the top of the footer component.  Is this possible?

Current issue:
[image]

If I disable the two overflow attributes in css on the slds-modal__content (shown below):

[image]

I get the desired result:

[image]

BUT, I cannot for the life of me, get this to work. When I pass in the modified css class slds-modal__content, it fills the screen with white. (When I set overflow: visible)

I am generating the component using the lightning:overlayLib using this code:

```
var modalHeader, modalBody, modalFooter;
    $A.createComponents([
        ["c:UWB_modalHeader",{'label':'Approve'}],
        ["c:UWB_utilityModal",{'modalName':'approve', 'approvalId':data.proccessInstanceToPiwi[data.approvalHistory[0].ProcessInstanceId], 'relatedObject':recordData}],
        ["c:UWB_modalFooter",{'cancelLabel':'Cancel', 'submitLabel':'Approve'}]
    ],
                        function(components, status){
                            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                modalHeader=components[0];
                                modalBody = components[1];
                                modalFooter = components[2];
                                component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                                    header: modalHeader,
                                    body: modalBody, 
                                    footer: modalFooter,
                                    showCloseButton: false,
                                    cssClass: 'slds-modal__content'
                                })
                            }
                        }
                       );
```

Where the css class 'slds-modal__content' is as follows:

```
.THIS .slds-modal__content{
    overflow-y: visible !important;
    overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```

Even after attempting to modify the class, the issue still persists. I have been successful with this method generating a standard modal without using lightning:overlayLib, but I'm not able to generate the modal in this way.